# How to find a paragraph by a string and replace a word in it in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `.mtl` file that contains few materials. It's like following,

```
newmtl Bed_Sh
Ns 96.078431
Ka 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Kd 0.640000 0.640000 0.640000
Ks 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000
Ni 1.000000
d 1.000000
illum 2
map_Kd 145349-red-fabric-with-floral-pattern-texture-free-high-resolution-photo.jpg

newmtl Bed_Wood
Ns 96.078431
Ka 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Kd 0.640000 0.640000 0.640000
Ks 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000
Ni 1.000000
d 1.000000
illum 2
map_Kd wood-textures_00248249.jpg
```

I need to identify the paragraph using `Bed_Wood` , `Bed_Sh` and replace the `map_Kd (imageName.jpg)`.

I tried with the following code.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

// getting path of the MTL file
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", @"test04", @"mtl"]];


NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];

NSError *error = nil;

NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"^map_Kd (.*)$" options:NSRegularExpressionAnchorsMatchLines error:&error];

NSString *editedContent = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:content options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [content length]) withTemplate:@"abc.jpg"];

NSLog(@"%@", editedContent);
```

This replace all the `map_Kd`s in the file. How can I do it with according to the paragraph header(`Bed_Sh, Bed_Wood`).

**EDIT::**
I need to identify the `map_Kd`s according to the headers(`Bed_Sh`, `Bed_Wood`)

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if ([fileContentString rangeOfString:@"Bed_Wood"].location != NSNotFound &&
[fileContentString rangeOfString:@"Bed_Sh"].location != NSNotFound) {
   NSString *editedContent = [fileContentString stringByReplacingMatchesInString:content options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [content length]) withTemplate:@"abc.jpg"];
}
```

or inside if

```
[fileContentString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"string to replace"
                                 withString:@"replacement"];
```

Comment: What is the type of `fileContentString`? unrecognized selector `stringByReplacingMatchesInString`

Comment: I want to replace the `Bed_Wood`'s paragraph `map_Kd` image to `abc.jpg` and `Bed_Sh`'s paragraph `map_Kd` image to `abcabc.jpg`. Is there any possible way to do it?

Comment: __fileContentString__ is string generated from file (I made up the name), in your case its named __content__.
use this method __replaceOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range__  where you find @"Bed_Sh" and newline character after that and range would be between these two locations

Answer (score 0):

You can make yourself a `NSArray` of chunks. You just have to split the entire string, e.g. with

```
NSArray *chunks = [inputString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
```

This would assume, that there is always an empty newline between every chunk. Another separator would be `newmtl`, but be careful, since the string that is used to make the split is removed. That is, you have to re-append `newmtl` to the beginning of every chunk.

Once it is splitted into chunks, search the array for your key and after replacement, re-combine the array to a single string.